# How to create Fixed Bid projects in OpenERP?

Tags: odoo

Im trying to implement OpenERP v6.0.0rc in my company which is an IT Services Company.
My boss told me to create Fixed Bid Projects. I searched a lot and found that OpenERP has no functionality to do so.
So i tried to do that using Analytic Accounts(fixed cost contracts).I create a new analytic account. Then tried to generate invoice by creating a new analytic entry manually.
Analytic Account->All analytic entries->New
But when i try to save that entry a warning pops up - 
                   "**Parent record doesnt exist**"

Tried a lot, cant get around this.
Please help me with this warning. 
Or if anyone knows any other way to create a fixed bid project.

Regards Nikhil

Comment: ok.. i got around that warning..was creating a new analytic account explicitly and trying to generate invoice. So instead i created a new project, and the analytic a/c was created automatically.

Now i can create and save analytic entries.. but when i invoice those analytic lines, i get a new warning-
"**At least one line has no product !**"

can anyone tell me what am i missing?
I know its a very silly thing, but its really got me stumped..

Comment: Hi Nikhil, welcome to Stack Overflow. It looks like you're asking more about how to use OpenERP, than how to write modules or edit the core project. I think this question would be more appropriate for http://superuser.com. If you don't get an answer there, you can also try the more traditional discussion forum on the OpenERP site: http://www.openerp.com/forum/

Answer (score 0):

Nikhil do the below.

1) Create a product type service.

2) Create a user.

3) Create an employee. Here is where you link a product and employee. When creating an employee go to the tab time sheet and there select the product of type service.

4) Now go back to your project task which you were working on and change the person you assigned it. Change it to the user employee/user you created in points 2 and 3.

5) Now make the time sheet lines and things should work fine.

all the best.